# Can I download a list of all apps I've PAID apple for?

Tags: ios-appstore

I've had an iPhone or iPod touch for years, and have bought tons of little apps, some free, some pay for.

I'd like to get a list of all the apps that I've paid for over the years, as there is one I'm trying to find, that I can't remember it's name!

When I browse my purchase history, it's got tons of free items listed as well, as I've installed tons of apps.

I'd like to download this list, and filter it to ignore things that were free. I only want to see things I've actually paid for.

Is this possible?

Note - I do not want to have to browse through my purchase history... I'd like to just install an app, or whatever I need to do to get a csv or spreadsheet of my purchases. It'd be nice if it included iTunes movie rentals as well ;-) Thanks!

Comment: You can [request a copy](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208502) of the data associated with your Apple ID. While I remember it gives you a list of the apps ever purchased (free and paid), I don't exactly recall if that also mentions if you got the app for free or paid a price. Requesting copy of data is the simplest way and your best bet to obtain the desired information.

Comment: @NimeshNeema - that sounds like a great idea.... I tried it out, and have requested all the data on that page, but noticed that it also says "Your download will not include App, book, movie, TV show, or music purchases." on the page.... But i think that means I wont get digital copies of those items, but the receipts for those items is probably there still. It says it can take up to 7 days... thanks for the idea!

Comment: You won't be getting digital copies of items. Just a CSV file listing them along with the relevant details.

Comment: I got the data from Apple, but it didnt include the prices apps were bought for, just a list of the apps, with various other seller information. Here's the header of what was in the file: `Apple ID Number,Activity Date,Content Type,Item Reference Number,Item Description,Version Text,Seller,Device Details,Device IP Address,Device Identifier
` and the file was `./Apple Media Services information/Update and Redownload History/iTunes and App-Book Re-download and Update History.csv
`

Comment: The only way I'm aware of to find out which of your purchases are "paid" (and what price) is to go to your iTunes desktop App -> Account -> Purchase History and scroll through year-by-year.   In iTunes for Windows, there is not an Export or Copy function to grab this data.    I suppose if you were ambitious, you could screenshot each page of your purchase history, then OCR it, then use something like Tabula to put it into a Table, then filter out using a spreadsheet.  Good luck. :-|

Comment: Complicated, might not be worth effort; You could set up a proxy to intercept your phone traffic and either get the response data directly from the proxy intercept, or at least find out the URL used to get the data for the app list.  I already have the tools at my disposal to do this but when I tried the app store wouldn't connect with my self-signed cert.  You might have more luck than me or you might have to use a jailbroken device to turn off the SSL checking.  There's tool call SSL killswitch https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/ssl-kill-switch2 that can do this.

Comment: interesting suggestion @apocalysque ! You may be able to trust your self signed cert [using the process detailed here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283348/7079). Otherwise, though I haven't tried it myself, this tool, [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) may actually make that work on the iphone, since it would proxy and have a cert that's fully trusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.  It can be done, but the way that I've discovered isn't easy.

I did try to get the info by intercepting iOS app store traffic but the data I got wasn't very clear.  Instead I intercepted traffic from an [older version](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-get-back-app-store-into-itunes/) of [iTunes](https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/itunes12/091-33626-20170922-F51D3530-A003-11E7-8324-03D19A97A551/iTunes64Setup.exe) that still has app store functionality in it.

Once you've fired up your [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (requires some [setup](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/TrustFiddlerRootCert) to decode HTTPS traffic) or whatever intercepting proxy you're going to use, open the older version of iTunes you installed and navigate through the menu **Account -> Purchased** and then click **Apps** in the upper right-hand corner.

[image: iTunes screenshot]

In your proxy monitor look for a request that starts with:

```
https://client-api.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStorePlatform.woa/wa/lookup?id=
```

There may be more than one of these requests, so make sure you grab the responses for all of them.  The response is issued in JSON format.  Luckily that JSON contains the data you're looking for...

[image: Fiddler screenshot]

Filtering JSON is beyond the scope of my answer right now.  It's getting late.  You might have an easier time using grep on some formatted JSON?  I'll see if I can give you the rest tomorrow.

Comment: wow... nice sleuthing! crazy to me that it's this hard to find out this information...  much appreciated! and no worries on the json, i can use `jq` or something like that to pull the data out if i like! and I'm giving you the bounty, even if a `better` answer comes up, you deserve it! and for those that are on a mac, or just wondering, it looks like you used `iTunes 12` ?

Comment: I agree, it shouldn't be that difficult to get the info.  Thanks for the bounty!  Yeah, the older version is 12.6.3.  That guide I linked says it works for both windows and mac, but I didn't want to mess up my mac by trying.  I couldn't care less if iTunes works on my windows box.  Fortunately the downgrade process was relatively painless.